# EWS : Mail added to Sent Items but not delivered

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am using Microsoft Exchange Web Services - EWS Managed API 2.2 to send mails from my Exchange Server email. 
Here's the code I am using :

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = CertificateValidationCallBack;
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1);
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("UserName", "Password", "domain");
service.Url = new Uri("https://exchangeserver.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
EmailMessage email = new EmailMessage(service);
//email.ToRecipients.Add("example@hotmail.com");
email.ToRecipients.Add("example@gmail.com");
email.ToRecipients.Add("username@domain.com");
email.Body = new MessageBody("BODY!");

email.SendAndSaveCopy();


//Here is my Certificate Validation function taken straight from MSDN :

static private bool CertificateValidationCallBack(object sender,
System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate,
System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain,
System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    // If the certificate is a valid, signed certificate, return true.
    if (sslPolicyErrors == System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.None)
    {
        return true;
    }

    // If there are errors in the certificate chain, look at each error to determine the cause.
    if ((sslPolicyErrors & System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors) != 0)
    {
        if (chain != null && chain.ChainStatus != null)
        {
            foreach (System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ChainStatus status in chain.ChainStatus)
            {
                if ((certificate.Subject == certificate.Issuer) &&                             (status.Status == System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ChainStatusFlags.UntrustedRoot))
                {
                    // Self-signed certificates with an untrusted root are valid. 
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (status.Status != System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ChainStatusFlags.NoError)
                    {
                        // If there are any other errors in the certificate chain, the certificate is invalid,
                        // so the method returns false.
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // When processing reaches this line, the only errors in the certificate chain are 
        // untrusted root errors for self-signed certificates. These certificates are valid
        // for default Exchange server installations, so return true.
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        // In all other cases, return false.
        return false;
    }
}
```

If I set the ToEmailAddress as the login username itself, the mail is being sent to inbox.
If I send to any other email address(tried gmail,hotmail,yahoo), the mail is deposited in the sent mail, but it is not delivered to the email address intended. 
But if I login to Outlook Web App and type a mail and send, the mail is added to Sent Items as well as delivered to the recipent email address.

I have checked Spam/Junk folder etc. The credentials are correct because I am able to save the copy of mail in Sent Items.

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: I would start by checking Messages Tracking https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124375%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx , you could also enabling tracing and look at the result your getting back from the server and also check the EWS Log files on the CAS server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the mail was being spammed out at the outgoing exchange server itself. If I set a meaningful Subject, the mail was being sent.

```
email.Subject = "Some meaningful subject";
```